# MySQL join table with 2 reference table

Tags: mysql

I have 5 table.

**product**

- id(PK)
- name

**description**

- id(PK)
- body

**price**

- id(PK)
- currency

**product_description**

- id(PK)
- product_id
- description_id

**product_price**

- id(PK)
- product_id
- price_id

Table `product`, `description`, `price` is where the actual data is stored.

And I want to join all the tables to assemble data.

My expected query result like this.

`product_id | product_name | description_body | price_currency`

I think join all the table and trigger condition with `on`.

But it is confused because I do not ever tried join table more than 3.

Is it possible with mysql query?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you do it *exactly* the same way as you would `JOIN` 3 tables, but with 2 more `JOIN`s. Give it a try and if it doesn't work, post your code and we can help debug it.

Comment: @Nick Below answer is works perfectly, but doesn't show if `product` has no `description` and no `price`. But I have to show it fill with `NULL`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure! you can join all that you want!

```
select * from product as p 
inner join product_description as pd ON p.id = pd.product_id
inner join product_price pp on p.id = pp.product_id
inner join price pr on pr.id = pp.price_id
inner join description d on d.id = pd.descripcion_id
```

Comment: I have one more question. If `product` id 2 has no `description` and no `price`, it doesn't show in query result. But I have to show it fill with `NULL`. Is it possible?

Comment: you should the use LEFT JOIN and/or RIGHT JOIN in such case. INNER JOIN only returns maching on both sides of the join, while left or right will keep record with no matching on the other side

Comment: I'm stuck in one more problem. If `product_description` has 2 rows that has `product_id=2`, it returns all of it. But I want to show only last one query. Can I trigger `limit` or `distinct` to it?